# Reverse engineering a ForEach block in a pipeline, where are variables stored?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

So I am reverse engineering someone else's work and I apologise, I am just a beginner.

So I have a pipeline, in the ForEach block it runs an array variable. I tried searching for it and I just couldn't find it at all.

[image: ForEach Block]

As you can see in items, there are variables('IDArray'). I don't know where these values are stored. The pipeline runs and succeeds but I tried looking for this variable and just don't know where to find it.

Comment: You can find the list of variables here https://i.imgur.com/VWK5L9j.png, just click anywhere on the pipeline and you can find them. apart from this what are you looking for?

Comment: You can use `{ }` to open pipelines definition in JSON format and then search for `IDArray`. Then you'll quickly get information about which activities use that variable and which might be changing the value of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **list of all variables of the pipeline** created here. Click anywhere on the pipeline pane apart from the activity and you can find the list of parameters and variables of that pipeline.

[image]

In General, in ADF variables can be created here or you can direcly create one variable when using **set variable activity**(Used when we assign variable value using dynamic content). **Looking at your pipeline flow, your array variable was created in the list and used a default value**.

Also, to get the total information about the variables of pipeline you can go through the **Pipeline JSON** in upper right as mentioned by **@jikuja** in comments.

[image]

Comment: Also very important to understand that Variables are global to the pipeline. As such, updating them inside a foreach can have unintended consequences. Good rule of thumb is to check Sequential if you reference variables inside the foreach activity.